# Style elements based on how many elements there are using just CSS?

Tags: css

I need to style label tags based on how many labels are in a containing div.

Example Code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <label class="checkout-item-promo" />
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
 <label class="checkout-item-promo" />
 <label class="checkout-item-promo" />
</div>
```

For the second div I need to add in bullets in front of the labels using the `:before` functionality of CSS3 but I only want it to happen if there are multiple labels within the wrapper.

Anyone have any tips or tricks for implementing this using **only** CSS?

Comment: This is not possible using only CSS, there is no parent selector yet

Comment: As seen below I don't believe this requires selecting the parent. Thanks for the response though Zach!

Comment: That only deals with the case of 1 child, not in the case of all number of children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the selector `:only-child` in combination with the `:not`. As I understand you want to add the bullets to all the labels if **there are more than 1 label in the div**, otherwise (there is only 1 label) the bullet should not be added. So you can try this CSS:

```
div.wrapper > .checkout-item-promo:not(:only-child):before {
  content:'* ';    
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Kpr8L/)

Comment: Excellent! This worked extremely well with a bit of tweaking for my actual code. I assume this is limited to browsers that support CSS3?

Comment: @Rinato I'm sorry that those selectors are part of CSS3, many other useful selectors are also part of CSS3, without them we almost can't do many things (instead we have to use script or some ugly workaround)... I think only really old versions don't support these features.

Comment: @KingKing King No worries! I just want to be able to tell my designers  which browsers this will work in. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Another way to do it, extensible to n elements http://jsfiddle.net/Kpr8L/1/ (just change (n+2) for whatever number you want)

Comment: If you want it to work in all browsers, you can use jQuery (if that's your thing). jQuery can recognize most CSS pseudo selectors, and you can add a CSS class to anything that matches your specific selection. I had to do that on a site recently that needed `nth-child` support in IE. That way, your designers don't have to worry about browser support.